# как сделать так, чтоб мой класс без явного приведения присваивался инту?

Tags: c++, ооп, перегрузка-операторов

У меня есть класс обертка, который должен присваивать к инту без явного приведения. По аналогии с классом bitset, который при вызовe [] возвращает ссылку на бит(класс обертку), но ее можно присвоить инту.

Comment: `operator int()` не устраивает? Неявное приведение устраивает? https://ideone.com/uAvrgy

Comment: Используйте [operator int() const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730153/c-class-converting-object-to-integer)

Comment: @Harry,  даже при наличии оператора приходится явно кастить

Comment: `даже при наличии оператора приходится явно кастить` Контрпример в первом же комментарии.